# How to quick check the input parameter?

Tags: algorithm

an input integer is limited by an array of data:
[Maski, possible-value-i], (i from 0-n)

which means the input param is a legal parameter only there is at least one i makes ,

param & Maski == possible-value-i,

Maski may equal to Maskj.

So far I have to check each Mask one by one for parameter legality.
Is there a way to compress these Mask checks to get a smaller one? (Or not the exact same check but I can use as a quick check for performance improvement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a circuit minimization problem. Each condition you have is of the form

```
x_i1 = m_i1 & x_i2 = m_i2 & ...
```

These conditions are then combined with the or - operator. You can simplify your expression using the [Quine-McCluskey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm).